# How to Channel list of you-tube cms account by you tube data api?

Tags: java, youtube-api, youtube-data-api, youtube-channels

I am using you tube data api to get channel list of a you tube cms account. My url is -
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=snippet,contentDetails&managedByMe=true&maxResults=50&onBehalfOfContentOwner={CONTENT_OWNER_NAME}&key={API-KEY}
but i am always getting this error -
You do not have permission to execute this method. 
Now i cant understand that what to do for this error ?

Comment: How to get permission ?

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same issue before, but in order to use onBehalfOfContentOwner parameter with the API, your CMS account must first have access to the Partner API. To enable Partner API and see it in your API options, you need to be whitelisted for that API. You need to contact support or an account manager from youtube to get whitelisted.